# Microsoft graph - License Overview

Tags: get, microsoft-graph-api, office365

Is there a possibility to build a Microsoft Graph GET request to get a license overview like this:

[image: License Overview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest Graph API endpoint is

```
GET /subscribedSkus
```

which returns the list of commercial subscriptions that an organization has acquired.

Check [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscribedsku?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of `subscribedSku` resource and compare them with [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msolaccountsku?view=azureadps-1.0#outputs) returned by `Get-MsalAccountSku`

Resources:

[List subscribedSkus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[subscribedSku resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscribedsku?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thank you, so according to that, it would be a request like: GET /subscribedSkus?$select=skuPartNumber,prepaidUnits,consumedUnits?

Comment: @ShadowGamb yes